# QuickBooks API: How to get the last time that an active QuickBooks connection was used?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Given that QuickBooks charges for each "active" connection, I want to implement some logic to automatically disconnect those connections that haven't been "used" for N months.
I know that Intuit will automatically expire the connection after 6 months, but I'd rather pay only 1 month if the user is actually not using the connection.

So my question: is there a way to know the last time that a connection was "used". That is, the token was used to make any kind of request (CRUD) to any of the QuickBooks API.

I suppose I could store that on my server, but I figured there might be a built-in way???

EDIT: Also, is there any way to get the first day of the billing period for that connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clement,
The connection is used each time your application makes an API call, so you would know that date. If you disconnect the user's connection they will have to login again and authorize if you want make another API call. (just FYI)

thanks
Jarred

Comment: It would be easier to look up the last call date in your local store than call an API to get that date.

Answer (score 2):

The Billing start date is the day after the free trial ends. The free trial period lasts 38 days and begins when the user connects the app for the first time. There is no API but this information is also available in the Connections report in developer center.